# Substract MYSQL timestamp fixed amount of hour where ID is something

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to make a line that removes a specific timestamp for a specific ID, I use MariaDB and havn'ut figured out how to.

```
X = some hour maybe 2 hours
TIMESTAMP = name of the table
Y = user id
```

What I want is something like:

Remove X amount of hours from TIMESTAMP where the id is Y

```
my timestamp format is not date it's like = 1414254628
below is on same table.
timestamp = 1414254628
timestamp2 = 1413646379
```

hope to get help, thanks!

sorry about the code blocks but but I had error on posting this thread so I had to make them look like codes

Comment: Do you want to update the value in your table or just select while subtracting two hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you store epoch time in your timestamp column you can just subtract the required number of seconds from it

```sql
SELECT timestamp - 3600 * 2 newtimestamp -- subtract two hours
  FROM users 
 WHERE user_id = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1652/5)** demo

---

> *...how do i actually update the value?*

By using `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE users
   SET timestamp = timestamp - 3600 * 2
 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e05/1)**

Comment: Hey, thanks the row goes through but it doesn't substract. and what does newtimestamp do?

Comment: Hey, did you look at the working demo I provided? `newstimestamp` is an alias for the column that holds the result timestamp value. You can name it however you want (e.g. `timestamp` again if you want to).

Comment: Okey, I get it thanks! but how do i actually update the value?